# How to get the default notification background color for custom notification in Lollipop?

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm having an issue with the color of my custom notification background in Lollipop.
It's black where it should be white.
The textColor is OK:

I'm using

```
<resources>
    <style name="NotificationText" parent="android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" />
    <style name="NotificationTitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title" />
</resources>
```

Any idea how to use the device default theme color for custom notification ?

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

Your app's targetSdkVersion must be 21.
As Ahmed's answere, add another styles file in values-21 folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <style name="NotificationText" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Notification" />
   <style name="NotificationTitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title" />
   <style name="NotificationTime" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Time" />
</resources>
```

Answer (score 5):

For whatever reason, there are new styles in Lollipop. Put this in values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="NotificationTitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title"></style>
    <style name="NotificationText" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Notification"></style>
</resources>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. My notification background is light gray where default is white.

Answer (score 0):

Create folder values-v21/styles.xml and past the below code,

```
 <style name="NotificationTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you have 2 options:

1) Target SDK 21, and custom notification will automatically use a white background

2) Copy your existing layout to layout-v21 folder and add android:background="#FFFFFFFF" to its root, like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" >

...

</LinearLayout>
```

Works great for me.

Comment: This is not working for me, because if you use lock, there is different color for widgets, therefore it will not look nice, if all are more gray and this one is white.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what the theme of the background is but I just set the background of my custom layouts (small view and large view) to a dark colour in the xml. This then matches the pre-Lollipop notifications more closely.

I find it bizarre that the appearance of android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title doesn't adjust to a dark colour for Lollipop when the standard notification colour is white!

Comment: I don't want to set a random color. I want the color to match the current theme. The color them isn't necessarily dark in pre-lollipop. It might vary from one manufacturer to another. And then it's white by default on vanilla lollipop. So I'm looking for a way to retrieve this 'official color'