# Lollipop notification background color

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I can't seem to make my notification use default notification background color: it remains gray where it should be white. At the same time, notification colors are appropriate in kitkat.

I have implemented suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26960072/1760858)

There doesn't seem to be any effect on what I implement. The values-v21 simply acts as if it weren't there.
Naturally, my target sdk is 21. I just can't seem to find the reason for this.

The notification is displayed from service using `StartForeground`. I have also tried `NotificationManager.notify()`, but it makes no difference.

Also, the notification is gray even if I only leave the wrapper RelativeLayout in the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

values-v21\styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="NotificationText" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Notification" />
  <style name="NotificationTitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title" />
  <style name="NotificationTime" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Time" />
</resources>
```

Though these styles aren't used anywhere else (like in my app theme declaration). They are just defined (in values-v21 and values-v9).

Comment: please post some of your code. Are you using NotificationCompat? Do you have a custom XML for your notification?

Comment: Yes, it's NotificationCompat.builder. Layout is a RelativeLayout, pretty complex (layouts overlapping & stuff). Is the layout relevant for the problem? I didn't want to post it because I thought it irrelevant.

Comment: You may have a solid background set in your notification's XML

Comment: Nope. I tried to do that, but it force closes, so there are no backgrounds set in the XML. Also: kitkat shows proper background color (dark gray) while lollipop shows light gray instead of white. This means colors DO depend on system scheme, but they are probably the wrong ones.

Answer (score 5):

> I can't seem to make my notification use default notification
>   background color: it remains gray where it should be white.

No. At least, not on Lollipop.

The darkish-gray background (`#ff424242`) will be used (in place of white) if you set `Notification.MediaStyle` on your `Notification.Builder` instance:

From [BaseStatusBar](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/BaseStatusBar.java#applyColorsAndBackgrounds):

```
protected void applyColorsAndBackgrounds(StatusBarNotification sbn,
        NotificationData.Entry entry) {

    if (entry.expanded.getId() != com.android.internal.R.id.status_bar_latest_event_content) {
        ....
        ....
    } else {
        // Using platform templates
        final int color = sbn.getNotification().color;
        if (isMediaNotification(entry)) {
            entry.row.setTintColor(color == Notification.COLOR_DEFAULT
                    ? mContext.getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.notification_material_background_media_default_color)
                    : color);
        }
    }
 ....
}
```

`isMediaNotification` checks if you are using `Notification.MediaStyle`. The following takes place if this check comes through:

```
if (No color was set on Notification.Builder instance using `setColor()`) {
    // R.color.notification_material_background_media_default_color 
    // is used as background
} else {
    // The color you set is used instead.
}
```

`R.color.notification_material_background_media_default_color`:

```
<color name="notification_material_background_media_default_color">#ff424242</color>
```

Perhaps you can confirm this by taking a screenshot of your notification and reading the `argb` value of its background. If the issue is introduced by `MediaStyle`, the color value will be as above. Even simpler approach would be to use `setColor(int)` on your Builder instance and see if that makes a difference.

This could very well be a Lollipop-specific thing since `MediaStyle` isn't available on < 21.

Comment: Hm, I'm using NotificationCompat.Builder and it doesn't have any `setColor` or `MediaStyle`. Also, the gray I get is light gray as in `#e0e0e0`. This gray is uniform across three different lollipop ROMs / devices.

Comment: @velis `#ffe0e0e0` is used for `low-priority` notifications: `<color name="notification_material_background_low_priority_color">#ffe0e0e0</color>`. Try leaving the priority at default.

Comment: @velis You're right about `MediaStyle` not being available in support library. `setColor` - [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor%28int%29).

Comment: That was it! low-priority is the culprit. I'm using it so that there's no icon in the status bar. Setting it any higer will make the background white, but also show the icon. You get the bounty :)

Comment: @velis Thanks. I thought about the issue - a way to keep normal priority & hide the status bar icon - doesn't seem possible yet.

Comment: Yeah, for now I "solved" it by setting the icon to a transparent image. Leaves a nasty space though :(

Comment: @velis :)) I tried that too, but didn't suggest it cos of the empty space it left. Would setSortOrder(String) make a difference? I haven't (and probably don't know how to) used it myself. It might do the trick if it pushes your notification to the end of the stack.

Comment: The problem is that this particulat notification is set by `service.startForeground()`. This automatically places it among the service icons and any "normal" notifications are placed later. So no, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<color name="notification_background_light">#fffafafa</color>
```

matched for me in Android 6 (Marshmallow).

See: [Guide lines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette) "Grey 50".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - my notification color was black on Lollipop while all other notifications were of system color (white). I could fix it by changing targetSdkVersion to 23