# How to change notification background color in android?

Tags: android

how do I change notification color in android? I tried this code but it only changed the title and icon color.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID).setColorized(true).setColor(Color.parseColor("#f7da64")
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363247/lollipop-notification-background-color

Comment: possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38022837/5167909

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure the Theme/Color used is consistent in

   - application tag of manifest file
   - all style files (style.xml,style.xml(v21))
2. Make sure in notificationBuilder.setColor(mNotificationColor) , mNotificationColor is really pointing to the expected color code.
3. Check if you are setting meidastyle as shown below

   .setStyle(new MediaStyle()
                           .setShowActionsInCompactView(
                                   new int[]{playPauseButtonPosition})in compact view
                           .setMediaSession(mSessionToken))